# It's better / it's best

Tags: grammar, superlatives, comparative

Should a comparative or a superlative be used in this sentence? Why?

In my experience, **it's better / it's best** to have only one best friend who is reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either 'it's better' or 'it's best'. If you choose the prior then it means having only one best friend -who is reliable- is a good thing, there is also a worse option (having unreliable friends, maybe) and there might be a better option (a reliable and drummer best friend, let's say).

However, you ask if you **should** use one of them or not. It totally depends on the context.

Comment: **Better** implies a comparison with another situation you have already mentioned.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, but there's only one sentence in OP's question; I gave my answer considering this.